# Pass a parameter to a Modal data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with c# in ASP.NET and I had the following doubt:

I want pass "ContentID" (when i click in button "Details") to Modal Window.

```html
@model IEnumerable<SoftIdeiaProject.Models.DB.Content>



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Details</h2>


@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateContent", Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values)
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var _item in Model)

    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => _item.Name)
            </td>

            <td>
                @if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteContent", new { id = _item.ContentID }) </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "AddVideo", new { id = _item.ContentID }) </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> @Html.ActionLink("Add Video", "AddVideo", new { id = _item.ContentID }) </button>
                }
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal" data-id="content_id_value">Details</button>



            </td>
        </tr>


    }
</table>
@foreach (var _item in Model)
{
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => _item.Name)</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => _item.Description)</p>

                    <p><img class="img-responsive" src="~/images/@_item.Image" /></p>
                    <p><video width="400" src="~/video/@_item.VideoID" controls/></p>
                        
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

For be more specific:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQO2F.png)

When i Click in "Details" of "Last" i want that the data on Modal be diferente that the "Pesquisa Rápida", but i can't do that.

Comment: can you put what is the code above details button

Comment: I already edit the post

Comment: @AbdulKhan Sorry for mistake

Comment: There is mistake in design  , you are making a loop with the same modal -pop. this loop will create multiple elements with same ID : id="myModal".

Comment: What is The Right form for i can do that dinamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say You have a ContentId field in your Model , generate unique buttons for each row  i.e.  instead of `data-target="#myModal"` make it  `data-target="#myModal_@item.ContentId"`

Details button should look like :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal_@_item.ContentId"   data-id="@_item.ContentId">Details</button>
```

Now In your second foreach Loop ,instead of

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
```

Make it unique

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal_@_item.ContentId" role="dialog">
```

Now you know the ContentId in each PopupId.

NOTE : I would strongly suggest having a single popup and just modifying the data inside that on details button click. you may also use ajax to get the data from server & bind it onSuccess.

[Refer here for a Way to achieve modal popup in MVC](https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1117/crud-operation-using-modal-dialog-in-asp-dot-net-mvc)